# Fragmenting a Tunnel Packet

Tags: ipv4, fragmentation

I was going through this Cisco Documentation - [Resolve IP Fragmentation, MTU, MSS, and PMTUD Issues with GRE and IPSEC](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/generic-routing-encapsulation-gre/25885-pmtud-ipfrag.html#anc2)

I have a confusion with example 3. Screenshot below.

[image]

As I understand, with the total of the header size would be 44 (New IP Header (20) + GRE Header (4) + Original IP Header (20)). As the example 3 mentions, a router in between the path has an MTU of 1400 bytes. So that leaves 1400 - 44 = 1356 bytes for the TCP Payload.

However, the example shows "1352 bytes", that is 4 short of a minimum MTU along the path of 1400 bytes. The remaining data of 104 bytes has been carried over to the next fragment.

Why is the first packet not a complete 1400 bytes rather 1396 bytes (1352 + 44) and have 100 bytes of the TCP payload added on to the next fragment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting the fact that the data must be fragmented on an eight-octet (64-bit) boundary. If you take the 1400-octet MTU and subtract the 44-octet header, that leaves 1356 octets for the data, but 1356 is not evenly divisible by eight: `1356 / 8 = 169.5`, but `169 x 8 = 1352`.

See [RFC 791, INTERNET PROTOCOL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791):

> To fragment a long internet datagram, an internet protocol module (for
> example, in a gateway), creates two new internet datagrams and copies
> the contents of the internet header fields from the long datagram into
> both new internet headers.  The data of the long datagram is divided
> into two portions on a 8 octet (64 bit) boundary (the second portion
> might not be an integral multiple of 8 octets, but the first must be).
> Call the number of 8 octet blocks in the first portion NFB (for Number
> of Fragment Blocks).  The first portion of the data is placed in the
> first new internet datagram, and the total length field is set to the
> length of the first datagram.  The more-fragments flag is set to one.
> The second portion of the data is placed in the second new internet
> datagram, and the total length field is set to the length of the
> second datagram.  The more-fragments flag carries the same value as
> the long datagram.  The fragment offset field of the second new
> internet datagram is set to the value of that field in the long
> datagram plus NFB.